# WCF get caller's Domain or IP, not client's Domain or IP (using jQuery Jsonp)

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp

Here is the scenario:
1. Let's say I have a lot of partners, each partner has it's own website
2. I provide all partners a piece of javascript code, this javascript will call my WCF using jQuery and Jsonp
3. Each partner add a link to their home page, and include this javascript
4. A user(anyone) go to PartnerA's web site, and click the link, this will trigger the javascript and call my WCF

My question is, how can I get the call's domain name or ip address? That is to say, I　ｗａｎｔ　ｔｏ　ｋｎｏｗ　ｔｈｅ　ｃａｌｌｉｎｇ　ｏｆ　ＷＣＦ　ｉｓ　ｆｒｏｍ　ＰａｒｔｎｅｒＡ　ｏｒ　ＰａｒｔｎｅｒＢ　ｏｒ　ＰａｒｔｎｅｒＣ．．．．．，　ｂｅｃａｕｓｅ　Ｉ have to distinguish different biz logic.

"Request.referrer" cannot, because not all browsers supports it.
I don't want the javascript pass domain name or ip address to my WCF, because javascript is in client side, that means everyone can use the same code calling my service, that will spoil my business logic.

Is there any back-end solutions to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just give each website a different piece of JaveScript, maybe a modified header info, where you put the partners specific ID.

Comment: Then everyone can get this ID by view source code of partner's page. So I can create a HTML on my local and use this ID to get partner's benefits.